# Need to go through 2 objects at the same time with VUEJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, v-for

I just want to throught POSTS and USERINFO at the same pace, in a way that in show the right user avatar for a given post

### Objects

```
   posts : {!! $posts !!},
   userinfo : {!! $userinfo !!},
```

### Template

```
< v-cloak v-for="post in posts">
  <div v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + post.picture + ')' }">
<a href="{{-- url("#" v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + userinfo.avatar + ')' }"></a>
</div>
```

Dont know how... basicly...

Comment: your datasets aren't datasets, they are variables, please provide a minimal example we can use, that works

Comment: @DerekPollard each posts has title,body,picture and each user has an avatar,name. What I wanna do is go throw posts[1] user.avatar[1] and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way (IMHO) is to provide the data to the template in a correct way, so the template just loops through the data the least amount of time.

To support that a `computed` value may be the easiest way to implement.

You can create a complex loop using js in you computed value, and then you reduce any complex logic in the template. This may also reduce the number of renders or re-computations needed if other parts of the component or template are changing.

other options are to update data.variable using a watch or from an api callback

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a property id to your user object.
And a property userId to your post object to avoid mistakes.

User has to be a prop of your element to be used into it